# Is there a good computer program for searching for endomorphisms between finite algebras which make diagrams commute? Is this problem NP-complete?

Tags: computational-complexity, computer-algebra, universal-algebra

Let $(X,*),(Y,*),(Z,*)$ be finite algebras. The binary operations $*$ are not required to satisfy any identities though I am interested in the special case where $*$ is associative. Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Z,g:Y\rightarrow Z$ are homomorphisms. Then is there already an optimized computer program that searches for homomorphisms $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$ where $g\circ\phi=f$? Is the problem of finding such a homomorphism $\phi$ an NP-complete problem? Is this problem still NP-complete when all operations are associative?

Comment: The name Agnes Szendrei pops to mind. Though it may be someone else who did the work, I think she was involved in computer search and enumeration of morphisms (whether iso, hom, or endomorphisms I don't remember).  You might search such work within the last twenty years for the program her team used.  Gerhard "Sorry I Don't Remember More" Paseman, 2017.02.11.

Comment: I found this software https://labix.org/python-constraint. I don't know if it is good or not though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mentioned this problem to one of my students, Kevin Berg, who proved that this homomorphism factorization problem is NP-complete when considered for the class of all finite algebras in a language containing at least 2 unary operations or containing at least one operation of arity at least 2. He also proved that the problem remains NP-complete when restricted to algebras with one associative binary operation (i.e. for semigroups). His arxiv preprint is here:

[The Complexity of Homomorphism Factorization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.01817)